# How to create a enum field with default value?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

```
  types = { # add your custom types here
          'attendance': ('Notconfirmed','Coming', 'Notcoming', 'Maycome',),
          }

  CREATE TYPE attendance AS ENUM types;
```

The above query creates enum type attendance with enumlabels mentioned in types. How to create a type with default label? In this case the I want to create attendance type with default value Notconfirmed.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

I was trying the same as you, and I got answer in stackoverflow only, It is possible to create ENUM with default value. Here is what I got for you.

```
CREATE TYPE status AS ENUM ('Notconfirmed','Coming', 'Notcoming', 'Maycome');

CREATE TABLE t (
    id serial,
    s status default 'Notconfirmed' -- <==== default value
);

INSERT INTO t(id) VALUES (default) RETURNING *;
```

This worked for me like a charm.

Comment: Or for an existing table
```
CREATE TYPE statuses AS ENUM ('Notconfirmed','Coming', 'Notcoming', 'Maycome');
ALTER TABLE t ADD status statuses default 'Notconfirmed';
```

Comment: ERROR: cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression

Answer (score 8):

*In addition to Sudarshan's words...*

In case someone needs an example in different schema:

```
CREATE TABLE schema_name.table_name ( -- 
    id serial,
    s schema_name.type_name default 'Notconfirmed'::schema_name.type_name
);
```

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure why we need to have below query in our table. I have tried without this line still works.

```
INSERT INTO t(id) VALUES (default) RETURNING *;
```